# PHP вставить переменную в строку

Tags: php

Как в такую строку вместо знаков ?(знаков вопроса) вставить переменные? Перерыл много сайтов, не могу разобраться. Знаю что в C++ так можно.
Например:

```
$a = 'SELECT * FROM ? WHERE id = ?';
$b = какая-то_функция($a, 'table', 5);
```

Надо в итоге получить таку строку:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 5
```

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/ просто оставлю это здесь

Comment: а что вы используете mysqli или pdo

Comment: я использую mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вопрос стоит именно в подстановке переменной в строку то можно использовать функцию [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php)

А если вам нужно именно для формирования запросов к СУБД, тогда лучше использовать [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php)

Пример из документации:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->execute(array(150, 'red'));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
```

А если вы используете [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) и не хотите его менять, тогда используйте [mysqli::prepare()](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php)

Пример из документации:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$city = "Amersfoort";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name = ?")) {

    /* связываем параметры с метками */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $city);

    /* запускаем запрос */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* связываем переменные с результатами запроса */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $district);

    /* получаем значения */
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

    printf("%s находится в округе %s\n", $city, $district);

    /* закрываем запрос */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

можешь так =)

```
$a = 'SELECT * FROM '.$table.' WHERE id = '.$id.';
```

или сложнее
но тут через prepare и т.д.

```
"INSERT INTO `messages` (`time`, `message`, `uid`) VALUES(?,?,?)");
```

[документация по mysqli_prepare на php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Никогда не стоит так делать. PDO или Mysqli

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше решение?